# Two column list with only one with bullet points

Tags: two-column

I am trying to do reproduce a two column list:

1- the left column shows a traditional list (thus a bullet symbol) and each item is separated by a blank space (I'm guessing `\bigskip`)

2- the right column shows a "sublist" of the first items list. No bullet points for this column. Both columns are separated with a line (but not the lines with the `\bigskip`).

I guess an image is really worth 1000 words...

I've tried the *listliketab* package without much success.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try with a tabular or a longtable.

Comment: The space separating the  item label from the item body is `labelsep`.`\bigskip` is a *vertical* spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using `xltabular` that combines the features of `longtable` and `tabularx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{l|>{\itshape}X}
-- Classification A & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
-- Method B         & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
-- Method C         & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\
-- Classification A & some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text  \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
-- Method B         & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
-- Method C         & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\
-- Classification A & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
-- Method B         & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
-- Method C         & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\
-- Classification A & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
-- Method B         & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
-- Method C         & some text \\
                    & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

The first column is left aligned and automatically as wide as its widest entry. The second column is justified and all entries in this column are italic (done with `>{\itshape}`). As you might notice, the table is a little bit smaller than the surrounding text. If you want to remove this indentation, use `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}l|>{\itshape}X@{}}` instead.

The vertical line is introduced automatically. To add the gaps in the line and the vertical white space between the blocks, I have used `\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\`. Pagebreaks can occur between every row of the table. If you want to prevent a pagebreak use `\\*` instead of `\\`.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

I used a very similar format some time ago. Using the technique employed by `leandriis` to separate the rows of the tabular, the following is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{mynewlist}{%
\sffamily %% Used this to match your sample -- change at will
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
    topsep=0pt,
    label={},
    left=0pt,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    partopsep=0pt,
    before=\vspace{-6pt},
    after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
}
    \begin{tabular}{>{--\ }l|>{\itshape\begin{itemize}}p{2in}<{\end{itemize}}}
}{%
    \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\mysep}{\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\}%% Inserts empty tabular row

\begin{document}

\begin{mynewlist}
Classification A&\item some text \item some text \item some text \item some text\\
\mysep
Méthode B&\item some text \item some text \item some text \item some text\\
\mysep
Method C&\item some text \item some text \item some text \item some text\\
\end{mynewlist}

\end{document}
```

The formatting of the table makes straightforward use of the `itemize` environment (with the help of `enumitem` which gives easy access to formatting lists) in the second column. The `array` package allows for adding formatting to the columns of a `tabular` environment -- in this case it allows for the automatic adding of the en-dash to the first column, and makes possible the use of the `itemize` environment and italic type in the second column of the tabular. Changes are easily made to suit your formatting requirements.

### Update

Made a small addition to `\setlist` of `leftmargin=0pt` to improve the spacing of the `itemize` environment in the second column. Updated graphic of output.

[image: itemize in tabular]

### Second update

For two reasons, I could not leave this alone. I wanted significantly to simplify the entry of the data, while at the same time making multi-page tables possible through the use of `xltabular.sty` (following the lead of `leandriis`). This required putting the entire body of the table into  `\itembody` by using `\gappto` from `etoolbox` -- a similar trick is needed for `tabularx` as well. As a simplification of sorts, I made `|` stand in place of `\item` to simplify typing, the use of which is strictly optional. I added a bit of color for fun. Also created a macro that handles the input neatly. I also used hanging indentation in the second column to indicate a very long line of text.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xltabular} %% multipage tabularx-style tables
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begingroup
    \catcode`|=\active
    \gdef\changebar{\def|{\item}}
\endgroup

\newenvironment{mynewlist}{%
    \sffamily %% Used this to match your sample -- change at will
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{red}
    \catcode`|=\active
    \changebar
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
        topsep=0pt,
        label={},
        left=0em,
        partopsep=0pt,
        leftmargin=1em,
        itemindent=-1em,
        before=\vspace{-1.25em},
        after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
    }%
}{%
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\bfseries--\ }l|
        >{\itshape\begin{itemize}}X<{\end{itemize}}}
            \itembody
    \end{xltabular}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \gdef\itembody{}%
}

\newcommand{\myentry}[2]{% gather the rows of the table into \itembody
    \gappto{\itembody}{%
        #1&#2\\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\[-8pt]%% Change '-8pt' to adjust space between rows
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mynewlist}

\myentry{Classification A}{%
    |some text
    |some text
    |some text
    |some text
}

%% The use of `|' for \item is purely voluntary.
\myentry{Méthode B}{%
    \item some text
    \item text that might be terribly long and go on and on and on\dots
}

\myentry{Method C}{%
    |some text
    |some text
    |some text
    |some text
}

\end{mynewlist}

\end{document}
```

[image: output from later version]

Comment: Output is actually pretty neat! Thanks for taking time to share this with me!