# How to line up two paragraphs in two columns separated by a red dot

Tags: two-column

I'm wondering how to achieve the formatting within each section of the example CV pictured below. I.e. I don't need to know how to do the whole thing, just the formatting from "GR Design Agency" to the bottom right of that section which says "Actualisation des tarifs clients". If it could be achieved without the bullet points I would prefer that.

The closest I have come is using this answer by leandriis: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498031/238485 but don't know how to align the text on the left to the right, have the line separating them be grey and get that red dot on the first line. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slight modification of [Bernard's answer to a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196808/134144), one can achieve the following output, that is at lease somewhat similar to the one shown in the question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\mybullet}{\makebox[0pt]{\color{red}\Large\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\phantom{\vrule width 1pt}\hspace{\labelsep}}

\newcommand{\myline}{\color{LightGray}\makebox[0pt]{}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}


\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{label=\scriptsize\textbullet, noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt, nosep, before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}, after=\end{minipage}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm} <{\hskip 2pt} !{\myline} X}
\multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm} <{\hskip 2pt} !{\mybullet}}{\bfseries text} & \large \bfseries more text here \\
text & \begin{tabitem}\item first item \item \lipsum[1][1-3] \end{tabitem} \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm} <{\hskip 2pt} !{\mybullet}}{\bfseries longer text} &  \large \bfseries more text here \\
multiple lines of text here & \begin{tabitem}\item \lipsum[1][1-2] \item \lipsum[1][1-2] \item \lipsum[1][1-3] \end{tabitem} \\
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```