# Two column nested list

Tags: multicolumn, xltabular

I'm producing a list very similar to this answer by leandriis https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498031/238485 but would now like to insert a list within the list, i.e. make it nested. In the image below, I would like to replace the text "replace me" with the list beneath it (from 'About' to 'Email'). The code I used to produce this can be found below. Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}r|>{}X@{}}
2017 -- 2019 & \textbf{Company 1} \\

                    & replace me \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
2015      & \textbf{Company 2} \\
   \textcolor{white}{2017 -- 2019}                 & some text \\
                    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
\end{xltabular}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}r>{}X@{}}
About: & some text some text some text some text some text \\
          Role:       & some text some text some text
 some text some text
 some text some text some text
 some text some text some text
 some text some text some text 
 some text \\
           Contact:         & some text \\
            Email:    & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
\end{xltabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the two lines of "some text" below "Company 2"? Do you also want to replace them?

Comment: Is this somehow related to [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/590190/134144)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three different ways to achieve the follwing output:

[image]

Which one to chose depens on the actual contents of your table. The first version makes use of `xltablar` and used 3 columns instead of just 2. This solution is sepecially useful, since it does not require manual calculateion of column widths.  This solution is somewhat limited to "some text" below "Company 1" occupying only a single line instead of multiple lines.

The other two suggestions use `longtable` and manually calsulated column widths and can also be used if you need automatic linebreaks in "some text" below "company 2". The first one used 3 columns, as well and is especially useful if your table contains more entries that follow the "Company 1" style than entries that follow the "Company 2" style. The second of the `longtable`-based suggestions makes use af just two columns in combination with a nested `tabular` and might be more useful, if your table contains more entries that follow the "Company 2" style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}r|rX@{}}
2017 -- 2019 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Company 1}} \\
             & About:   & some text some text some text some text some text \\
             & Role:    & some text some text some text  some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
             & Contact: & some text \\
             & Email:   & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
2015         & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Company 2}} \\
             & \multicolumn{2}{l}{some text} \\
             & \multicolumn{2}{l}{some text some text some text some text} \\
\end{xltabular}



\newlength{\firstcolwidth}
\newlength{\secondcolwidth}
\newlength{\thirdcolwidth}
\newlength{\combinedcolwidth}

\setlength{\firstcolwidth}{\widthof{2017 -- 2019}}
\setlength{\secondcolwidth}{\widthof{Contact:}}
\setlength{\thirdcolwidth}{\linewidth-\firstcolwidth-\secondcolwidth-4\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}
\setlength{\combinedcolwidth}{\secondcolwidth+\thirdcolwidth+2\tabcolsep}


\begin{longtable}{@{}wr{\firstcolwidth}|wr{\secondcolwidth}p{\thirdcolwidth}@{}}
2017 -- 2019 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Company 1}} \\
             & About:   & some text some text some text some text some text \\
             & Role:    & some text some text some text  some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
             & Contact: & some text \\
             & Email:   & some text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
2015         & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Company 2}} \\
             & \multicolumn{2}{p{\combinedcolwidth}@{}}{some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text} \\
             & \multicolumn{2}{p{\combinedcolwidth}@{}}{some text some text some text some text} \\
\end{longtable}


\begin{longtable}{@{}wr{\firstcolwidth}|p{\combinedcolwidth}@{}}
2017 -- 2019 &\textbf{Company 1} \\
             & \begin{tabular}{@{}wr{\secondcolwidth}p{\thirdcolwidth}@{}}
                About:   & some text some text some text some text some text \\
                Role:    & some text some text some text  some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
               Contact: & some text \\
               Email:   & some text \\
               \end{tabular}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
2015         & \textbf{Company 2} \\
             & some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\
             & some text some text some text some text \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!